# Minor typo in on-topic page

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [on-topic page](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> Working in a part-time **of** full-time setting for a company

(my emphasis). I suspect that should be "or" rather "of".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing that out. I edited it.